# Spectral analysis how coefficient are aj and bj are found?

Tags: time-series, spectral-analysis

I'm reading chapter 4 on spectral analysis from the "Time series analysis and its application", and I hit a bit of a confussion when it comes to how coefficients $a_j$ and $b_j$ are found. It said that it uses regression results from previous chapter to imply that its from the form

$\sum_{t=1}^{n} x_tz_{tj}/\sum_{t=1}^{n} z_{tj}^2$

Would be great if someone can explain the reason behind this section.

[image]

Comment: Vote to move question to SE Signal Processing forum.

Comment: It's simple linear regression. In this case there's no intercept term and the number of regressors is equal to sample size (so R squared is 1). In  other words, you're computing the expansion coefficients of $x$ with respect to the sine and cosine basis.